# array_pop() with Key

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following array

```
$array = array('fruit'     => 'apple',
               'vegetable' => 'potato',
               'dairy'     => 'cheese');
```

I wanted to use [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) to get the last **key/value** pair.

However, one will note that after the following

```
$last = array_pop($array);

var_dump($last);
```

It will output only the value (`string(6) "cheese"`)

How can I "pop" the last pair from the array, preserving the key/value array structure?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out `array_slice()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Last argument `true` is to preserve keys.

When you pass the offset as negative, it starts from the end. It's a nice trick to get last elements without counting the total.

```
$array = [
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2,
    "c" => 3,
];

$lastElementWithKey = array_slice($array, -1, 1, true);

print_r($lastElementWithKey);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [c] => 3
)
```

Comment: Ensure you set preserve_keys = true if your keys are numeric or you may not get the pair you expected!

Comment: This will work but doing a triple inline statement as the example may be confusing for newcomers, definitely don't recommend that part in your code.

Comment: This answer doesn't modify the array. Yes, for getting the last key/value pair, it's efficient enough, but the question wants "popping" and getting the last key/value pair. So, you should add an `array_pop()` after that (which reduces performance).

Answer (score 10):

try

```
end($array); //pointer to end
each($array); //get pair
```

Comment: Note: `each()` is deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0 (Current minor at time of comment.)

Comment: [`each()`](https://www.php.net/each) function is removed as of PHP 8.0.

Answer (score 7):

Why not using new features? The following code works as of PHP 7.3:

```php
// As simple as is!
$lastPair = [array_key_last($array) => array_pop($array)];
```

The code above is neat and efficient (as I tested, it's about 20% faster than `array_slice()` + `array_pop()` for an array with 10000 elements; and the reason is that `array_key_last()` is really fast). This way the last value will also be removed.

**Tip:** You can also extract key and value separately:

```php
[$key, $value] = [array_key_last($array), array_pop($array)];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `end()` and `key()` to the the key and the value, then you can pop the value.

```
$array = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'vegetable' => 'potato', 'dairy' => 'cheese');
$val = end($array); // 'cheese'
                    // Moves array pointer to end
$key = key($array); // 'dairy'
                    // Gets key at current array position
array_pop($array); // Removes the element
                   // Resets array pointer
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work, just don't do it inside a foreach loop (it'll mess up the loop)

```
end($array); // set the array pointer to the end
$keyvaluepair = each($array);  // read the key/value
reset($array); // for good measure
```

Edit: Briedis suggests `array_slice()` which is probably a better solution

Comment: [`each()`](https://www.php.net/each) function is deprecated as of PHP 7.2, and is removed as of PHP 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

function array_end($array)
{
    $val = end($array);
    return array(array_search($val, $array) => $val);
}

$array = array(
    'fruit' => 'apple',
    'vegetable' => 'potato',
    'dairy' => 'cheese'
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_end($array));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [dairy] => cheese
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
<?php
end($array);
list($key, $value) = each($array);
array_pop($array);
var_dump($key, $value);
?>
```