# PHP re-order array by selecting an item to be the first

Tags: php, arrays

I have a rather complicated issue that's probably related to `array_splice` but I can't figure it out. Here's an example of the array I have:

```
array(
 'a' => 'Element A',
 'b' => 'Element B',
 'c' => 'Element C',
 'd' => 'Element D',
 'e' => 'Element E'
);
```

What I want to do is reorder the array based on the key I select, say "c", such that the end result is:

```
array(
 'c' => 'Element C',
 'd' => 'Element D',
 'e' => 'Element E',
 'a' => 'Element A',
 'b' => 'Element B'
);
```

It basically moves the selected key to the front, while keeping the ordering intact. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you have they key `c` as input and you just want to move it to the top?

Comment: have you tried using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6933432/4786273) (to remove last element) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1371021/4786273) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12124318/4786273) (to add it at the beginning of the array) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_search()` will get the offset of `c` in `array_keys()` from the array.  Then `array_slice()` that and `array_merge()` with the modified original array:

```
$array = array_merge(array_slice($array, array_search('c', array_keys($array)), null),
                     $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most beautfiul solution but it works

```
$arr = array(
 'a' => 'Element A',
 'b' => 'Element B',
 'c' => 'Element C',
 'd' => 'Element D',
 'e' => 'Element E'
);

function doIt($key, &$arr)
{
   $tmp  = array();
   $tmp2 = array();
   $flag = false;
   foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
      if($k == $key) {
         $flag = true;
      }
      if($flag) {
        $tmp2[$k] = $v;
      } else {
        $tmp[$k] = $v;
      }
   }
   $arr = array_merge($tmp2, $tmp);
}
doIt('c', $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [c] => Element C
    [d] => Element D
    [e] => Element E
    [a] => Element A
    [b] => Element B
)
```

[Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf3267688ecd33bf66186566870fb4ca8adf6e8c)

Comment: Kinda ugly indeeed :p

Answer (score -1):

You should see the doc of sort() function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

in "User Contributed Notes" you will probably found the perfect function for your probleme !

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.